# How to add separators / dividers in Joomla 4 Custom Components (Sub-)Menu?

Tags: joomla-4.x, menu-item, xml, submenu

There are these nice loking seperators / dividers in the core content component's menu:
[image]

I've tried already to add the following in my XML without success:

```
 <menu class="divider">sep</menu>
 <dividingline />
 <divider />
 <dividingline role="presentation" />
 <divider role="presentation" />
 <separator role="presentation" />
```

com_content has this Preset xml where the menuitems are listed as menuitems and are grouped in "menuitems" - i think that's the clue.

I understand that "my" menu items are nested a level deeper - there is no existing way to implement such dividers there?

Comment: Menus items are hardcoded to have "component" type during component installation. You may report this on the issue tracker.

Comment: I've created https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/41123 for this request - thanks

Answer (score 1):

It can be done but you have to hack, manually change, the `#__menu` table in the database.

In your manifest .xml file you add a line between you menu items that will create a record in the `#__menu table` in the correct order

```
<menu type="separator">.</menu>
```

The `type="separator"` is not stored in the database as you would like it to, but it is parsed as a valid statement thus your manifest file wont fail on installation. The '.' is required, it can't be blank or you will get a message about a missing Title, however you can put a '-' or any other character. Whatever you put here will be displayed if you don't follow the next update the table.

You will have to Install or Discover your component to pick up the new menu item.

Next you have to alter this new record in  `#__menu` table and change the `type` field from `component` to `separator` and then line will appear in your components menu.

I agree with @sharky who replied in the comments while I was away trying to work out if this was possible, raise an issue to have this fixed and let us know the # and I will support it.

The code to display the separator is there in `..\administrator\modules\mod_menu\tmpl\default_submenu.php` there just needs to be a few changes in the installation of a component to change the type in the `#__menu table`.

**Update 10th July**

Line #1072 of ..\libraries\src\Installer\Adapter\ComponentAdapter.php that has this statement

```
$data['type']         = 'component';
```

and if you replace it with

```
$data['type']         = ((string) $child->attributes()->type) ?: 'component';
```

then the installer will update the `#__menu` table with whatever value is entered in the type param of the `<menu>`

Comment: Thanks for your test - I've created https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/41123 for this request

Comment: I have updated my answer to include what to change where and I will now update the Joomla Issue.